# How to clean up the list of Terminated AWS EMR clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I have about 88 EMR clusters that are terminated in my AWS account.
How do I clean up the list of terminated EMR clusters? Will AWS clean up the list?

How come I don't see the terminated clusters being removed from the list of clusters just like how the EC2 instances page looks like?

Thanks!

Nicholas

Answer (score 7):

You can't really clean them up, the job flow you created in last two weeks will show up if you call `elastic-mapreduce --list`.

The way I solve this problem is `elastic-mapreduce --list --active` to check only the active jobs.

Or, you can filter them by date `elastic-mapreduce --list --created-after=DATETIME`

> Lists all clusters created after the specified time and date in XML date-time format.

Answer (score 6):

Terminated clusters are removed from the console when the metadata is removed and Amazon EMR preserves metadata for two months.

Reference link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-gs-reset-environment.html

Answer (score 5):

It is common to have a one-job cluster, a cluster terminating with its job(i.e. cluster terminates), and not waiting for a new one to come. So in case if data about finished clusters is cleared just after termination, it would be harder or even impossible to analyze its statistics, parameters of performed job, reasons of failure (if any) and so on.

Do not bother about terminated clusters, data will be cleaned from the list within two weeks time-frame.